# Java Application not recognizing my collections in my MongoDB databases.

Tags: mongodb, jakarta-ee, mongo-collection

I am creating a simple web application and I am attempting to connect the application to MongoDB. Here is the class where I am establishing the connection.

public class JavaMongoDBConnection {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
    MongoClient mongoClient = null;

        mongoClient = new MongoClient();

    List<String> databases = mongoClient.getDatabaseNames();

    for(String dbName: databases) {
        System.out.println("Databases: " + dbName);

        DB db  = mongoClient.getDB(dbName);

        Set<String> collections = db.getCollectionNames();

        for(String colName : collections) {
            System.out.println("\t + Collection: "+colName);

        }

    }
    mongoClient.close();


    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

}
}

When I run this class as a Java application, this is my result

Databases: admin
Databases: budget
Databases: config
Databases: db
Databases: local
Databases: myTestDB

However, when I go to terminal and I run the following commands, here are my results.

1. show dbs

Response:
admin     0.000GB
budget    0.000GB
config    0.000GB
db        0.000GB
local     0.000GB
myTestDB  0.000GB

2. use myTestDB
3. show collections

Response:
Budget
budget
myCollection

So, why are Budget, budget, and myCollection not showing up when I run this java application??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the current version of the MongoDB Java Driver (currently [3.7](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.7/)), use `MongoDatabase` instead of `DB`:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();

for(String databaseName : mongoClient.listDatabaseNames()) {
    System.out.println("Database: " + databaseName);

    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(databaseName);

    for(String colName : db.listCollectionNames()) {
        System.out.println("\t + Collection: " + colName);
    }
}

mongoClient.close();
```

The above code should have an output similar to the following:

```
Database: admin
         + Collection: system.version
Database: config
         + Collection: system.sessions
Database: local
         + Collection: startup_log
Database: test
         + Collection: testcoll1
         + Collection: testcoll2
```